# how can the conditional pdf remain a pdf when the negligible set of the conditioning random variable overlaps?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, number-theory

here is a lemma:

> the jointly continuous r.v X, Y are independent. iff $f_{y|x}(y|x) = f_y(y)$ for all $x$ outside a set $E$ with $\int_E f_x(x) dx = x$

However, consider a case, for example with $Y ~ N(0, 1)$ and $X ~ Exponential(1)$. If this makes $f_{y|x}(y|x)$ defined only on $x \ge 0$, wouldn't it fail to be a pdf (in particular, it wouldn't integrate to 1)?

Comment: Why would you not be able to integrate $f_{y\mid x}(y\mid x)$ over $y\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is undefined on $y \in \mathbb{R}_{< 0}$ @Manifoldski

Comment: No, it is undefined in $x<0$. There is nothing restricting $y$

Comment: It can be easier if you think about what an actual dependence would look like, it could be $Y \sim N(0, 1+X^{2})$ where $X$ is Exponential$(1)$. The $X$ does not put a strain on the possible values of $Y$, just changes the shape of the distribution.